# Black screen when I try to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, display, monitor

I am trying to install Ubuntu but a problem persists: When I boot from a USB drive (with the iso in there) appears the load screen of Ubuntu and after that my monitor apparently fails to fit the resolution of the installer (which is rare because it had previously been adapted in the load screen). I could hear the characteristic sound of the Ubuntu boot and nothing else. Does anyone know what the problem is? The same thing happened to me when I tried to install Linux Mint.

**Monitor** - 24-inch Noblex TV as the monitor. Connected to the PC with RGB cable.

**CPU** - *i5 4690*

**GPU** - *GTX 970*

Comment: Can you include the type of monitor you have? It may not be important information (I'm not sure), but it could be used to help solve your issue.

Comment: It's actually a TV. 24-inch Noblex, connected to the PC with an RGB cable. Yes, I have to replace it with a new one soon. But you know, third world and stuff.

Comment: I added it to your question. Hope you get it solved soon.

Comment: Does it work if you add the `nomodeset` boot parameter in GRUB?